# Rails asset pipeline and serving static files from nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm trying to access a file logo.png from my rails app. During the deploy process everything in /app/assets gets compiled and placed into /public/assets. For example my file which had been named logo.png looks like this:

```
/public/assets/logo-e66eddecdb08ac2b7fe349da2a065d87.png
```

When I try to access that full filename nginx successfully serves it up directly because of these lines in my /etc/sites-enabled/myapp:

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
root /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/public
```

So I can browse to myserverhost.com/assets/logo-e66eddecdb08ac2b7fe349da2a065d87.png and it loads fine. However of course in my app I have that file referenced simply as "logo.png" and when I load my home page I'm getting a 404 not found on the logo.png.

How is nginx supposed to know that the filename has been mashed up with a hash at the end?

EDIT: I reference the logo file like this in my scss file:

```
#sidebar .logo-div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid#ddd;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  text-align:center;
  background-image:url('logo.png');
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: How are you referencing `logo.png` in your view?

Comment: edited my question with that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use an url helper.

`background-image: url(image-path("logo.png"));`

or 
`asset-url("logo.png", image)`

Rails automatically adds the hash in production.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a `css` file:

```
background-image: url(/assets/logo.png);
```

If your file is a `sass` file can use the helper:

```
background-image: image-url("logo.png");
```